Terminal de Ubuntu tarda en encontrar el directorio y no responde hasta que aparece el directorio
Estoy experimentando un problema al abrir la terminal en Ubuntu. Cuando inicio una nueva terminal, ésta se abre, pero tarda mucho tiempo en mostrar el prompt con el directorio actual. Durante este tiempo, la terminal no responde y no puedo ejecutar ningún comando hasta que finalmente aparece el directorio.
Este retraso es bastante molesto, ya que afecta mi flujo de trabajo. ¿Alguien sabe qué podría estar causando este comportamiento y cómo solucionarlo?
Agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Te doy la bienvenida. Échale un vistazo a la respuesta a esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261602/how-can-i-debug-the-bash-prompt La idea es entrar por ssh sin que cargues el .bashrc (que es el script qu ese ejecuta cada vez que abres una terminal) para tener un entorno limpio y despues cargarlo pero haciendo primero set -x para activar la depuración y ver que se está ejecutanto y en que punto se queda parado. A lo mejor con eso identificas el problema.

Tambien mira la variable $PS1 que puede que ejecute comandos que tarden y eso este relentizándote, por ejemplo si el comando trata de conectar a otro host y no hay conectividad, el comando se va a quedar bloquedo hasta que haya un timeout.
